# Filtering a sql query based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    order_number int PRIMARY KEY,
    client varchar(20),
    revenue int,
    fixed_transport_cost int,
    income int,
    order_date date
)
```

What I expect is this:

> Select clients whose first order was placed in 2017 and calculate how
>   much income was genereted in 2018 (total) per each of them.

What I have tried is this:

```
 SELECT 
     clients, SUM(income) 
 FROM
     orders 
 HAVING 
     YEAR(order_date) = '2018' 
     AND income = ANY (SELECT income FROM orders 
                       WHERE YEAR(order_date) = '2017') 
 GROUP BY
     income;
```

But looks an incorrect query. My question is how to check if someone already ordered in 2017?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, HAVING clause should be place after GROUP BY clause.
2. Second, you should check for first order in 2017 not any order in 2017. This is what you asked for. In fact, HAVING should not be necessary here.
3. You need to group by client as you are looking for sum of income per client (if I understand well).

You could try the following query:

```
 SELECT 
     client, SUM(income) 
 FROM
     orders 
 WHERE
     YEAR(order_date) = '2018' 
     AND client IN (
          SELECT client 
          FROM orders 
          GROUP BY client 
          HAVING MIN(YEAR(order_date)) = '2017')
 GROUP BY
     client;
```

OR

```
 SELECT 
     o1.client, SUM(o1.income) 
 FROM
     orders o1
 WHERE
     YEAR(o1.order_date) = '2018' 
     AND '2017' = (
          SELECT MIN(YEAR(o2.order_date))
          FROM orders o2
          WHERE o2.client = o1.client)
 GROUP BY
     o1.client;
```

Please provide a sample of data if you want us to try the query and give you a demo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me why you're mentioning HAVING is not necessary? As far as I know it should be used whenever there is group by, isn't it?

Comment: HAVING clause is only necessary if you want to apply a filter on the result of your group by (i.e. a filter on each grouped row returned). If no filter need to be applied at this specific moment, then having clause is not mandatory after group by.